# How do I change the background using an image from another file?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, background, onclick

I am making a website to keep track on my moviecollection. I have a page called "list.php" which lists all my movie titles. Each title is clickable. When you click the movie, an ajax function will retrieve information about the movie from another file called getmovie.php. Then a div expands and the information is being placed inside the expanded div. That was quite easy to make. To make the site more fancy I want to switch the background of list.php to be a poster from the "clicked" movie. The database stores the path to this poster, and getmovie.php will get that. But how can I change the background in list.php to a path being stored in getmovie.php?

Basicly I have a variable containing a path to an image I want to set as background in another file. How am I supposed to code that?

Thank you :)

Comment: You could send the path along with the rest of the markup in your AJAX call, and then split it out with a script and handle it separately.

Comment: Or you could even include a script tag inside whatever is generated by `getmovie.php` which will make the appropriate call, assuming you're loading HTML and not raw data or JSON or something.

Comment: @TMan, not good, definitely not good. Don't teach that to others

Comment: @Alexander And your reasoning being?

Comment: I figured it out... inside the ajax function, I added:
var result = self.xmlhttp.responseText;
var splitted = result.split('[background_path]');
var background = splitted[1];
var output = splitted[0]+splitted[2];  self.document.getElementById("divmovie"+divid).innerHTML=output;
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('"+background+"')";

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use javascript to change document.body.background when you call the ajax function. For example, in the playMovie() function:

```
document.body.background = "images/movie01.jpg";
```

Hope it's useful.

Comment: Changing background using javascript is easy, the problem is that the path is stored in another file. I have to load that file and access its pathvariable.

Answer (score 0):

As I tested with different methods, It is not possible to set a page's background from another page. However you can set the image from the page itself. You should do 2 ajaxs.. First you should get the text with a simple ajax as you have done that already. and Second get the background. write a php script that gets a movie input and displays ONLY the image url in the browser and then do an ajax and set the background of the new page using the retrieved url.